# data structures arrays

Tags: arrays

iv read up on many journals and ebooks and programming solutions, but have not yet understood which array structure would be best for searching, sorting, deleting and adding?

what would be the best array to use?
vector array?
static array?
linked list? or binary tree?

Comment: Linked lists and binary trees are generally not referred to as "arrays".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a lot to do with the data you are trying to store.

Linked lists and trees are not considered to be arrays, because the amount of stored data can dynamically increase and/or decrease. If you know the exact size of your data set, maybe an array is a good choice.